# Can, in theory, information escape an event horizon via a specialized setup?

Tags: black-holes, research-level, hawking-radiation, information

Can, in theory, information escape an event horizon via a specialized setup?

Specifically, send a beam of photons to be barely—just *barely*—inside the event horizon, then wait for hawking radiation to deplete the horizon's size before the photon can fall in, allowing the photon to escape after being inside the event horizon?

Comment: Half of the people who study black holes do so out of a conviction that information will escape an event horizon in *any* setup.

Comment: The event horizon is not a membrane that lets stuff in but not out. It's much worse than that. You cannot send a beam of light toward the horizon from inside because there is no "toward the horizon" from inside. If you are inside, then every direction you can point your flashlight is "toward the singularity." Every direction that you yourself can go is toward the singularity, and it's not even possible for you to keep still.

Comment: Your question is based on misconceptions. (1) It is impossible to send photons to the inside. Nothing crosses the horizon ever from our external perspective. (2) The information paradox happens outside the horizon before anything crosses it. (3) Photons cannot cross the horizon before the black hole completely evaporates. (4) As the horizon shrinks, nothing from the inside is getting out. And so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a particular case of the information loss puzzle. There are two schools of thought:

1. Information must be retrieved at any cost. Somehow, something will recover the information lost to the black hole eventually. When it evaporates, somehow the information will be retrieved, or perhaps it doesn't even completely evaporate at all.
2. Information might be lost and we just move on. There are many physicists, myself included, who believe that the information sent into a black hole is lost forever and that's it. See arXiv: [1703.02140 [hep-th]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.02140) for a review of this point of view.

At any case, no one truly knows the answer to your question yet.

Comment: “*no one truly knows the answer to your question yet.*” - Read the actual question. Everyone knows the answer.